# SQL query LIKE statement error

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-python, cacti

I am new to mysql database. I have to make a query to filter name_cache which includes **TNY or eth0** in my query! 
This is my current query--

```
SELECT data_template_data.data_source_path, data_template_data.name_cache
FROM data_local, data_template_data,host
WHERE data_local.id=data_template_data.local_data_id AND
      data_local.host_id=host.id
HAVING data_template_data.name_cache like "%TNY%eth0"
ORDER BY data_local.id;
```

---

> ```
>     data_source_path                               | name_cache                      
> | <path_rra>/r1f-sinx03ztny_traffic_in_15846.rrd | R1F-SINX03ZTNY - Traffic - eth0 |
> | <path_rra>/r1f-sinx04ztny_traffic_in_15857.rrd | R1F-SINX04ZTNY - Traffic - eth0 |
> | <path_rra>/r1f-wzrx79ztny_traffic_in_16343.rrd | R1F-WZRX79ZTNY - Traffic - eth0 |
> ```

I want to only validate with tsp short name(TNY in WZRX79ZTNY). Help me how should i query for it?

Comment: Having is generally used when a group by is present I would use a where clause in the query.(this won;t resolve your issue just saying)

Comment: SELECT data_template_data.data_source_path, data_template_data.name_cache FROM data_local, data_template_data,host WHERE data_local.id=data_template_data.local_data_id AND data_local.host_id=host.id WHERE data_template_data.name_cache like "%TNY%eth0" ORDER BY data_local.id;

Comment: i got error 
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE data_template_data.name_cache like  '%TNY'' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  So, your query (with table aliases) is:

```
SELECT td.data_source_path, td.name_cache
FROM data_local l JOIN
     data_template_data td 
     ON l.id = td.local_data_id
     host h
     ON l.host_id = h.id
WHERE td.name_cache like '%TNY%eth0'
ORDER BY l.id;
```

You are not using `host` (unless to check that `l.host_id` is not null).  Similarly, you don't need `data_local`.  So, I think this does the same thing that your query does:

```
SELECT td.data_source_path, td.name_cache
FROM data_template_data td
WHERE td.name_cache like '%TNY%eth0'
ORDER BY td.local_data_id;
```

For this query, there is not much you can do.  You might be able to use an index on `data_template_data(local_data_id)`.  Unfortunately, the wildcard at the beginning of the `like` prevents the use of an index.

If you are looking for words, you might be able to use a full text index.

Answer (score 0):

use WHERE, not HAVING.
also using single quote, not double quote
consider using JOIN so the table relation ship more clear

```
SELECT data_template_data.data_source_path, data_template_data.name_cache 
FROM data_local
INNER JOIN data_template_data ON data_local.id=data_template_data.local_data_id
INNER JOIN host ON data_local.host_id=host.id
WHERE data_template_data.name_cache like '%TNY%eth0' 
ORDER BY data_local.id;
```

but i don't see you use anything from table host so i think you can exclude that from your query

```
SELECT data_template_data.data_source_path, data_template_data.name_cache 
    FROM data_local
    INNER JOIN data_template_data ON data_local.id=data_template_data.local_data_id
    WHERE data_template_data.name_cache like '%TNY%eth0' 
    ORDER BY data_local.id;
```

Comment: Thanks. I also want to reduce CPU usage when running the query, My orginal query hits to 100% of cpu usage so any other way to make it?